# DITDetermining if ID exists in class list

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to determine if a player already exists in players list, if they do I want to update their data, however if they are not in there, I was to add them. The issue that I am having is that obj is being set to selectedPlayer and therefore it isn't null and it overwrite the old record instead of adding a new one.

```
var obj = Variables.players.FirstOrDefault(player => player.MembershipID  == selectedPlayer.MembershipID);
if (obj != null)
{
    obj = selectedPlayer;
}
else
{
    Variables.players.Add(selectedPlayer);
}
```

Basically I have an add/edit form, I am trying to see if the membership ID already exists in the list of players. If it does, edit the relates player in the players list. If it doesn't exist in the players list, add it

**EDIT**
Sorry guys, worked it out, turns out that because selected player was a public variable, when I changed the parameters in that, it changed in the Variables list.

Comment: But selectedPlayer isn't in the List yet

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = Variables.players.FirstOrDefault(player => player.MembershipID  == selectedPlayer.MembershipID);

if (obj == null)
{
    Variables.players.Add(selectedPlayer);
}
else
{
    //use obj
}
```

When you say edit the relates of the player I guess you want to update related properties of the player object.

In above code by **//use obj** means you could do things like that:

```
 obj.OtherProperty = selectedPlayer.OtherProperty;
```

Note: OtherProperty is just an example. Please refer to properties of object which are required to be updated.

Or you could simply remove and insert object at same index of the player list, as mentioned in other answer.

Comment: This still presents the same issue

Comment: You want to update found `obj` with selected player?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on what your issue is with `obj` there, since your logic looks like it's meant to do exactly what you're saying it's doing. Perhaps you meant to swap your `obj != null` to be `obj == null`?

In any event, it looks like what you want to be doing is more like this:

```
if (!Variables.players.Any(player => player.MembershipID  == selectedPlayer.MembershipID))
{
    Variables.players.Add(selectedPlayer);
}
```

---

Although I'd be tempted to either override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` functions of your player type, or create an `IEqualityComparer`. Then you could use a `HashSet` that would handle exactly what you want to do. Obviously that's only relevant if you have control over `Variables.players`.

```
class PlayerComparer : IEqualityComparer<Player>
{
    public bool Equals(Player a, Player b)
    {
        if (a == null)
            return b == null;
        else if (b == null)
            return a == null;
        else
            return a.MembershipID == b.MembershipID;
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you can instantiate `Variables.players`:

```
public HashSet<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>(new PlayerComparer());
```

And, use it as follows. This function will return true if it was added, or false if it already existed in the list.

```
Variables.players.Add(selectedPlayer);
```

---

**Edit:**

Alright, maybe I get it now. Thanks to [Selman22's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25194503/1270504), I get the impression that you want to update the item in the original list to have the values from `selectedPlayer`?

If that's the case, then I think there might be a bit of misunderstanding about variable passing in C#. When you call `obj = selectedPlayer`, you aren't actually changing anything about the original value of `obj`. You are, instead, changing where the memory that `obj` is referencing *is*.

You want to, probably, do something like this:

```
var temp = Variables.players.FirstOrDefault(player => player.MembershipID  == selectedPlayer.MembershipID);

if (temp != null)
{
    Variables.players[Variables.players.IndexOf(temp)] = selectedPlayer;
}
else
{
    Variables.players.Add(selectedPlayer);
}
```

Note, of course, that some of these operations (the `int` indexer property and use of `IndexOf`) are dependent on the type of `Variables.players`, which we aren't given.

In order to illustrate what your original code did, here's a short console program:

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;

Console.WriteLine(a); // 5
Console.WriteLine(b); // 5

b = 2;

Console.WriteLine(a); // 5
Console.WriteLine(b); // 2
```

As you can see, this creates two variables (I picked the `int` type since it's an easy way to illustrate the same point), one equal to the other, then writes each out, then changes one of them to another value, then writes each out again. The comments indicate the results. As you can see, the latter assignment to `b` is not propagated back through to `a`. You would need another `a = b` to reflect the change in that respect.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to replace old `obj` with `selectedPlayer` if it does exists:

```
if (obj != null)
{
    int index = Variables.players.IndexOf(obj);
    Variables.players.RemoveAt(index);
    Variables.players.Insert(index, selectedPlayer);
}
```

Comment: Well interpreted. It didn't even occur to me that `obj = selectedPlayer` might have been an attempt to replace the original value rather than the reference, but that's a great point. I have absolutely no idea whether this one will be what the OP was looking for, but +1 for creativity.